# Play Framework - where can I find the release notes or the "what's new" document?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-1.x

Looking allover the net, I could not find any references neither for such a document for Play 2.0.1, nor any roadmap. If anyone knows, please point it out for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From google group announcement:

### Release notes:

issues: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/milestones/current

corresponding code changes: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commits/2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

You can find release notes on the Play Framework changelog page: http://www.playframework.com/changelog

And the current Play 2.x roadmap is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/11sVi1-REAIDFVHvwBrfRt1uXkBzROHQYgmcZNGJtDnA/pub